# Laravel auth nothing happen when trying to login with default laravel auth page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have previously transferred laravel from server to another by copying the laravel project folder, now when i try to login using default laravel auth page , if i enter wrong auth value i get error auth.failed
but when i enter a valid auth value the page refresh but nothing happen.
I notice from browser view source the value of CSRF token is changing one i enter the valid auth value

I tried to delete the session files /storage/framework/sessions 
and tried

```
php artisan view:clear

php aritsan cache:clear
```

but nothing happen.
How can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) for easily debugging such kind of cases.
It's good, simple and sweet ^

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

In the previous server i was using SSL for my domain so the cookies setting in /config/session.php was true:-

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
```

Since, the current new server i am not using https when i open my website, so i set the value to false

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

Now everything working fine.